# Tensorflow gradients causing contractive autoencoder cost doesn't converge

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist, autoencoder

To construct a contractive autoencoder, one uses an ordinary autoencoder with the cost function
[image]

To implement this with the MNIST dataset, I defined the cost function using using tensorflow as

```
def cost(X, X_prime):
    grad = tf.gradients(ys=X_prime, xs=X)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X_prime - X)) + tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(grad))
    return cost
```

and used AdamOptimizer for backpropagation. However, the cost doesn't go any lesser than 0.067, which is peculiar. Is my implementation of the cost function incorrect?

**Edit:**
After reading the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/gradient_computation) on`tf.gradients`, the above implementation would have computed 
[image] instead. So my question is, how do you do derivatives component wise in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

To address your post-edit question: TensorFlow doesn't have a function that computes Jacobians. The following quote, taken from a [Github discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675), sketches how you might compute the Jacobian yourself:

> Currently, you can compute the Jacobian of, say, a vector, by calling gradients multiple times, one for every scalar component (obtained by slicing) of the original vector, and reassembling the results.

Answer (score 0):

So just like Akshay suggested, the way to compute the Jacobian is through slicing the differentiation target. Below is a little example.

[image]

The Jacobian matrix of f is

[image]

The code in tensorflow

```
X = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(10, 3)), dtype=tf.float32)
y = X[:, :-1]

jacobian = tf.stack([tf.gradients(y[:, i], X) for i in range(2)], axis=2)

sess = tf.Session()
j = sess.run(jacobian)
print(j[:, 0, :])

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Which gives